# Error when bundle install-ing - `Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rails"`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, bundle

I'm trying to install a gem, I updated it in the gemfile, then `bundle install`.

I received the following error message:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rails":
  In Gemfile:
    merchant_samples (>= 0) ruby depends on
      rails (~> 3.2.9) ruby

    rails (3.2.7)
```

What does it mean? What can I do? I'm using rvm, do I need to switch to another version of ruby? of rails? and if so, which one and how? and why :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What that means is that merchant_samples gem requires rails `3.2.9` or higher and you are using version `3.2.7`. So to use it you need to upgrade your rails version to `3.2.9` at least, but you should actually update to the latest `3.2.*` since there are some security issues on older versions. At the moment the newest version is `3.2.13`

You can upgrade changing your Gemfile to:

```
gem 'rails', '3.2.13'
```

Then you must run `bundle` and everything should be working.